# xquery and data input as xml from a relational database

Tags: xquery, saxon

I'm using xquery to work with a relational database.  I was thinking of implementing some sort of SAXSource, DOMSource or StreamSource that would be hooked up to a relational database as the data input.  Run an xquery and have saxon return the result xml as output stream.  The relational database to xml will be very simple xml structure representin a data input to saxon.  Anyone done this before or have sample codes that I can look at?  Just need to see how i can build an input stream from relational database and how I would call Saxon to utilize that as the input stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem would be performance. Saxon would treat the database simply as a big XML file to be loaded into memory, it wouldn't do anything to translate predicates from your XQuery or XPath query into SQL predicates that the relational database engine could use for optimization (e.g. by using indexes in the database).

But apart from that, writing a class that reads a SQL table and emits a sequence of SAX ContentHandler events to present it as a flat XML structure doesn't sound at all difficult, and once you've done that it's easy to wrap this into a SAXSource so that Saxon can read it directly.

Comment: I can't seem to wrap my head around creating a SAX ContentHandler class that emits a sequence of events and then using this class wrapped in a SAXSource so that I can feed it to Saxon directly.  Do you have some simple sample codes that i can look at?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have a simple example that does this. You don't have to supply the ContentHandler. You could use the TransformerHandler interface. Write a program that reads the SQL database and makes a sequence of startElement() and endElement() calls to the TransformerHandler.

Comment: Can I get an instance of the TransformerHandler from Saxon so i can do the startElement and endElement calls?

Comment: If you're using the JAXP API, use Templates.newTransformerHandler().

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Saxon SQL extension module would be enough for you? http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sql-extension/

Comment: No, i wanted to use actual xquery language that I can use to query and not extension sql's.  Thanks though.